# Difference between ElGamal and Schnorr signature

Tags: discrete-logarithm, schnorr-signature, elgamal-signature

A question about Schnorr group.
Am I right that this is basically a protection against discrete-log solvers?
So Schnorr signature is better than ElGamal in that sense?

Comment: Did you see this; [DSA vs. ElGamal vs. Schnorr](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/10388/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka Ah, thanks for the link